# waitforsingleobject for an already signaled event

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, visual-c++, synchronization

I do `WaitForSingleObject(handle, timeout);`
if handle is already signaled before the call to `WaitForSingleObject`, what will the function return?

I thought it should immediately return a `WAIT_OBJECT_0`...but in my case, it waits for the event to be set and since that does not happen (the event is already set), it times out.

Pls advise.

Comment: Yeah - what @Roman says.  If you want to save the signal/s, either use a manual reset event or a semaphore.

Comment: If the `WaitForSingleObject` times out then it means your handle is not signaled.  As previously mentioned it might be because you're using an auto-reset event (that has previously had `WaitForSingleObject` or `WaitForMultipleObjects` called on it.  Or you have a bug somewhere else in your code.

Answer (score 9):

Depends on event. What you expect is true for manual reset event, and auto-reset events don't keep the signaled state: [Event Objects (Windows)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682655%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

> Auto-reset event  An event object whose state remains signaled until a
>   single waiting thread is released, **at which time the system
>   automatically sets the state to nonsignaled**.
>
> If no threads are waiting, the event object's state remains signaled.
>   If more than one thread is waiting, a waiting thread is selected. Do
>   not assume a first-in, first-out (FIFO) order. External events such as
>   kernel-mode APCs can change the wait order.